# Convert Timezone to UTC SSIS package

Tags: ssis, dynamics-365, kingswaysoft

I worked on creating a SSIS datamigration using `kingswaysoft` for Dynamics. i was tried to migrate `createdon` field from source to destination, once migrated there is a time difference of *12 Hrs*, CRM time zone is set to *GMT+12* for both source and destination, it looks like its migration time in UTC so is there a way in SSIS packages to convert UCT to GMT+12? or is there any expression i can use to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our CDS/CRM Source component, there is an option to select the Output Timezone. The Output Timezone option specifies how CRM datetime values are produced. There are three options available.

- UTC (Default)
- Adjust to timezone of Connection User
- Adjust to timezone of Impersonation User

If you are going to use "Adjust to timezone of Impersonation User", make sure that you have the "Impersonate As" set.

[image: KingswaySoft CRM Source Component Editor Screenshot]

Similarly, our CDS/CRM Destination Component includes an optional setting to "Send datetime values in UTC format". This option indicates whether datetime values should be submitted to CRM server in UTC format. This option will apply to all datetime fields when selected. When not selected, the datetime values are submitted based on the timezone setting of the connection or impersonation user.

[image: KingswaySoft CRM Destination Component Editor Screenshot]

Finally, our SSIS Productivity Pack also includes the Time Zone Conversion component which is used to convert values from a date column from one time zone to another. The component also automatically adjusts for daylight saving changes when converting between different time zones including UTC.

[image: KingswaySoft Time Zone Conversion Component Screenshot]

Let us know which solution works for you and as always, feel free to [reach out to our Support team](https://www.kingswaysoft.com/about-us/contact-us) if you have any further questions.